# The C++ analog of norm in C

Tags: c

I noticed that the C++ version of `<complex>` has [`norm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/norm/).

However, I am programming in C, and there is no `cnorm`.  So I made one to define before my `main` function:

```
#include <complex.h>

double cnorm(double _Complex z)
{
    return cpow(creal(z),2) + cpow(cimag(z),2);
}
```

How would you improve this definition? Is the name ok?  or will it break when it is eventually added to `<complex.h>`.  Is the return type appropriate?  Would it be more consistent to use `double _Complex`?  And is the implementation efficient (for rapid numerical evaluation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code presented suffers from both performance and precision problems.  `pow()` and `cpow()` work by converting to logarithms and multiplying.  To square a floating-point value, it's quicker and more accurate to multiply it by itself:

```
#include <complex.h>

double cnorm(double _Complex z)
{
    const double r = creal(z);
    const double i = cimage(z);
    return r*r + i*i;
}
```

You *could* multiply `z` by `conj(z)` (the imaginary terms ought to cancel), but the function above is cheaper and works in the `double` domain.

`cnorm()` is not reserved by the Standard; [the names reserved for future `<complex.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier) are

> `cerf`, `cerfc`, `cexp2`, `cexpm1`, `clog10`, `clog1p`, `clog2`, `clgamma`, `ctgamma` and their -`f` and -`l` suffixed variants

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer (I am the OP)!  Are you saying that `cpow(complex, integer)` does *not* use binary exponentiation?  That means my hundreds and hundreds of calls of `cpow(complex, integer)` in the main body of my program is slowing everything down!  Does `<complex.h>` not include a rapid implementation of calculating powers of the form "complex raised to integer"??  Thanks again!

Comment: There's no overloading in C, so the only `cpow`  is [`double complex cpow(double complex x, double complex y)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/cpow).  Your compiler *might* convert calls with a constant integer `y` to multiplication using the "as if" rule, but I think it's unwise to rely on it.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I should write my own function to compute complex numbers raised to integers.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Related question:  How would you recommend implementing a rapid and accurate reciprocal?  Is `cpow(z,-1)` out the question?  How about `(1.0/z)` ?

Comment: Again, I'd expect the compiler to produce better code for `1/z` than for the `cpow(z, -1)`.  I can't back that up with facts, though.

Answer (score 3):

I most cases the `norm` for complex numbers means the magnitude/absolute value, so if you want Gauss' definition you might think about a different name.

If you want it really fast and and with an error of at most one ulp it gets quite complicated. You might download a version of Cygwin's new-libc (e.g. from the git here: https://github.com/mirror/newlib-cygwin) and take a look at `newlib/libm/math/e_hypot.c` to get the gist of it.

What you have now is quite slow and imprecise, for two reasons:

- the return of `creal()`/`cimag()` is a `double`, no need for the complex function `cpow()`.
- you have two squarings and one addition; all three together have a good chance of unnecessarily adding error.

There is the function `cabs()` which computes the Euclidean norm `sqrt(a²+b²)`. I would propose to use that function and simply square the outcome if you do not want to go the long and complicated way. If `cabs()` is implemented well (error less than 1 ulp) you should get a good error value for your own function, too.

Comment: Computing the square root unnecessarily sounds like a bad idea for performance, and probably for precision as well.

Comment: @200_success that was meant as an alternative to the otherwise long and complicated but fast and precise (error < 1ulp) way to do it. It is still faster than OP's code (assuming a proper implementation of `sqrt`) and more precise. It is even more precise than `a*a + b*b` for some input.  It is also simple.